# Problem with read-only SD card on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, disk-utility, monterey, sd-card

I have a micro SD card that is set to read-only that I can not get fixed. I have tried the common tips such as:

- Switch the lock on the card. I have tried different positions, like in the middle, almost at the top etc.
- Restarted my Mac
- Pushed the SD card in as fast as I can
- Opened Disk Utility and tried "first aid" and then "erase", but it just fails:

```
Deletes "NO NAME" (disk2s1) and creates "NO NAME"
Disables disk
Could not change partition map. : (-69874)
The action failed…
```

- Resetting the PRAM
- Tried putting the micro card in another newer carrier card with a newer switch lock, and tried the different positions again on the switch
- I have also tried some commands in Terminal:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 SDCARD MBRFormat /dev/disk2
>>Unable to begin erase operation: A writable disk is required (-69772)
```

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS FAT32 SDCARD MBRFormat /dev/disk2
>>Unknown partition scheme: SDCARD
```

```
diskutil list
>>
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 ⁨NO NAME⁩                 32.0 GB    disk2s1
```

```
diskutil listFilesystems
>>
MS-DOS                          MS-DOS (FAT)                                    
MS-DOS FAT12                    MS-DOS (FAT12)                                  
MS-DOS FAT16                    MS-DOS (FAT16)                                  
MS-DOS FAT32                    MS-DOS (FAT32)                                  
  (or) FAT32
```

Any other tips on how I can fix this problem? BTW/ the format of the card is: MS-DOS (FAT32), I have an MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), macOS Monterey version 12.5.1 and I don't have any Windows computers available.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only It usually means the drive is toast, if there was a write error the firmware will switch to 'protect' mode, which is read-only.

Comment: TBH/ whenever I have a problem with an SD card, I back up the contents to my computer, purchase a new card, and throw away the 'bad' one. No sense in trying to figure out what is wrong with it. At the very least, back up the data (if there is any you need to keep) before you fix it - you may end up with data loss. SD cards are ephemeral in the scheme of things.